# "four years ago"

Tags: vocabulary

> From the time our party took office **almost four years ago** the
>   number of people unemployed city-wide increased by less than 20
>   percent.

the time four years sounds a bit ambiguous to me. Does that mean that the party first took office four years ago, and they have been having the office for four years? Or does that mean they took the office before four years, but  they were not able to have the office for the period of four years?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Almost four years ago* further describes *the time our party took office*. You could replace it for example with the precise date, like "the 3rd of April 2014" and would get almost the same meaning. But the author focusses on the time span, not the point in the past, so he or she conveniently does the math for you.

Your first suggestion is correct:
The party took over almost four years ago and is still in office.